# How do I fix that liquid particles not rendering?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, mantaflow

When I try to final render my particles they don't render.

Preview

[image: preview]

Render

[image: Rendered]

Comment: I figured it out. I had to switch replay and modular.

Comment: Are those foam particles or what kind of particles? And how did you get them to render just by switching _Replay_ to _Modular_? You need objects to render as foam particles, the cache type doesn't change anything about it.